# Trying to achieve responsive boxed structure using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve a structure like below on a webpage
https://www.figma.com/file/NfikH1inSqCgwXOSzb3VeDCW/Untitled?node-id=0%3A1

So the full width is max width 1600px. Problem is, making it responsive has become very complex.
Reason is, all the boxes are given width in percentages.
So first whole section is divided in 2 parts 50% left – 50% right.

Inside 50% left – I have added 4 images by giving 50% width

Inside 50% right – I have added 1 image by giving 100% width

If we use just images in this structure, it stays very responsive if I reduce the screen size.
But as there are texts added BELOW each images, the box that contains the text has fixed width (66px). When we reduce the screen size, this disturbs the layout responsiveness.

Any solution to make it proper responsive?
I tried making the text box as an overlay to the image, so position absolute bottom of the image which fixes the issue but then the bottom part of the image goes behind the text box.
I want to make sure the image stays full visible and the text box also stay below it.

Any thoughts? I am happy to use JS too if there is a good solution.

Comment: show the code which you have tried @aslam

Comment: Instead  of providing 50% width to images, use 4 sections with width:50% and inside these sections add the image and text

Comment: Please provide the expected results. How you want your layout to be reformed when window is resized and at what screen size?

Comment: I'm down voter. I'm really sorry because of this but your question refers to an external site which may not be available in future. Also I don't see any code or what you have tried so far. In addition, question title `Trying to achieve responsive boxed structure using CSS` Don't help any body in future. Please modify your question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.fifty {
   width: 50%;
   padding-bottom: 66px;
   position: relative;
  }
  .parent {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  img {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
  }
  .left {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  p {
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   bottom: 10px;
   transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
  .pb-0 {
   padding-bottom: 0;
  }
    .child {
      border: 1px solid #333;
    }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 <div class="left fifty pb-0">
  <div class="fifty  child">
   <img src="https://dummyimage.com/350x250/aae0ff/aae0ff" alt="image"/>
   <p>Text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="fifty  child">
   <img src="https://dummyimage.com/350x250/aae0ff/aae0ff" alt="image"/>
   <p>Text</p> 
  </div>
  <div class="fifty  child">
   <img src="https://dummyimage.com/350x250/aae0ff/aae0ff" alt="image"/>
   <p>Text</p> 
  </div>
  <div class="fifty  child">
   <img src="https://dummyimage.com/350x250/aae0ff/aae0ff" alt="image"/>
   <p>Text</p> 
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="right fifty child">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/350x250/ffa0a0/ffa0a0" alt="image"/>
  <p>Text Right</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

I think you want something like this, if needed anything else, Please let me know

Comment: That's Great. I added one more small thing in this

img{
  object-fit:cover;
}

as the images were stretched